# Makefile error - File not found - *.cpp

Tags: c++, linux, windows, makefile, mingw

So, I try to compile a game in a personal GameEngine made in c++. I use a makefile to compile all the files. Compiling on Linux is good but on Windows, with MinGW, I get these errors :

```
C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\Code\GitProjects\HyperGameEngine>make
sh.exe
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
File not found - *.cpp
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - D
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
g++  -o "/build"/a.exe  -I"./inc/lua/" -I"inc" -I"./inc/" -I"./inc/SDL2/" -
L"lib/Windows" -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -std=c++14 -std=gnu++14 
-Wunused-parameter -Wstrict-aliasing -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_net -mwindows -
lglew32s -llibSOIL -lopenal32 -lopengl32 -lBox2D -lfreetype -llua53 -dl
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot 
open output file /build/a.exe: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** ["/build"/a.exe] Erreur 1
```

Here the makefile :

```
#TODO Authoritive Server, Basic Server Browser (Hearthbeat to web server)? (maybe steam support)?
#
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

$(info $(SHELL))
ifeq ($(shell uname -s), Linux)
TARGET_EXEC ?= a.out
endif
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
TARGET_EXEC ?= a.exe
endif

BUILD_DIR ?= "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/build"
SRC_DIRS ?= "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/src" # src or Server

#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name *.s)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

ifeq ($(shell uname -s), Linux)
CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -g -Wall -Wextra -O3 -fpermissive #-Werror
endif
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -lmingw32 -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -g -Wall -Wextra -O3 -fpermissive -mwindows #-Werror
endif

 #LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against -L/usr/lib/nvidia-375/ -I./inc/ -w -lGLEW -lGL -lSLD2
ifeq ($(shell uname -s), Linux)
LINKER_FLAGS = -I./inc/ -I./inc/lua/ -L./lib/Linux/ -lSDL2 -lGLEW -lGL -lSOIL -lopenal -lBox2D -lSDL_net -llua53 -lfreetype -ldl
endif
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
LINKER_FLAGS = -dl # -I"./inc/lua/" -I"inc" -I"./inc/" -I"./inc/SDL2/" -L"lib/Windows" -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -std=c++14 -std=gnu++14 -Wunused-parameter -Wstrict-aliasing -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_net -mwindows -lglew32s -llibSOIL -lopenal32 -lopengl32 -lBox2D -lfreetype -llua53 -dl #-I"./inc/steam/" -lsteam_api #-llua53 -dl
endif

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    g++ $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS)

# assembly
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.s.o: %.s
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# c source
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    g++ -std=c++0x $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# c++ source
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@


.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SRC_DIRS)

-include $(DEPS)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
```

Then, all the libraries work on Linux and I tried to reinstall MinGW but nothing change. Some changes in the makefile did something. Changing the order of the LinkerFlags in Windows section was the thing that small the error message.

Comment: I guess, `File not found - *.cpp` is a follow-up error. The actual error is probably the `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.` I would check all MinGW build tools isolated (e.g. does `g++` work when called directly, does `make` work when rules fire only `echo`s, `cp`s, or `touch`s, etc.)

Comment: If you want to use Linux commands like `uname` on windows you'll need to use something like MSYS or Cygwin. A better solution would be to use make's built-in variable `MAKE_HOST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem isn't MinGW..
By my understanding, MinGW is a set of compilers. So, gcc and g++.

> MinGW includes:
>
> A port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), including C, C++, ADA
> and
> Fortran compilers;
>
> GNU Binutils for Windows (assembler, linker,
> archive manager);
>
> A command-line installer, with optional GUI
> front-end, (mingw-get) for MinGW and MSYS deployment on MS-Windows;
>
> A
> GUI first-time setup tool (mingw-get-setup), to get you up and running
> with mingw-get.
> http://www.mingw.org/

If you are able to run g++ on a single "hello world" file and get an exe, MinGW should be working.

So, it seems that most MinGW and gnuwin32 are not the problem!
As user657267 points out, you can't use Linux commands on Windows..
This said, that doesn't mean it's impossible, just not there by default.
One way to "make" this works is to install Git (https://git-scm.com/download/win)
You can choose the all default options...
After you install, go to the installation path and past the path to the bin folder to the Path Environment Variable.
Here's a [screenshot of my Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33tlN.png)